# How to pass data from PerformSegue in monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, ios5, xamarin.ios

I have table source class and on row click I am calling below function to move to another controller but I want to pass some data.

```
controller.PerformSegue("backtorootviewsague",controller);
```

Does any knows how can I achieve it. I am new in monotouch  and ios. I cannot figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`PrepareForSegue` is the right place to do it. For example, if the controller that creates 
`CustomerViewController` is called `CustomerListViewController`, override in `CustomerListViewController` that method like the following:

```
public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
    base.PrepareForSegue (segue, sender);

    // do first a control on the Identifier for your segue
    if (segue.Identifier.Equals("your_identifier")) {

        var viewController = (CustomerViewController)segue.DestinationViewController;
        viewController.MyData = dataToInject;
    }
}
```

where `CustomerViewController` has a public property like the following:

```
public SomeTypeData MyData { get; set; }
```

You could see this in action in [Xamarin samples](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/WorldCities).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much it was very useful. But I am keep this error. I followed exactly the same way. `[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.`

Comment: Could you debug and see where it crashes?

Comment: but how can I do it if I am calling this function in Table Source Class

Comment: it crashes exactly when I calling this `var view = (RootViewController)segue.DestinationViewController;`

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't correct. The crash say the cast it's not correct. Why do you use `RootViewController`? Also try remove `CustomerViewController controller =  new CustomerViewController();`. Have you followed the sample I provided?

Comment: Sorry, actually, once I followed the sample you provided I removed `CustomerViewController controller = new CustomerViewController();` To the question you asked why do I use RootViewController. It is because I am now in CustomerViewController and calling RootViewController.

Comment: So what I did that I pass object of `CustomerViewController` to TableSource and in row select call this function `controller.PerformSegue("backtorootviewsague",controller);` Rest as you mentioned

Comment: The crash says that you have a cast error. The destination controller hasn't the correct type. Check it. Maybe follow that sample and you will overcome the problem. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot find a problem. can it be because of ipad development

Comment: @Akrambek No. It's quite difficult to understand what is going on. I really suggest to download Xamarin code and see how it works. Open a new answer for the other problem you have and provide details on it. If you want, mark also my answer as correct since I replied to your first question. Cheers.

Comment: Hi, I found the problem. The issue was I calling `(RootViewController)segue.DestinationViewController;` in `UIViewController` however screen I want to move is TabBar Controller

Comment: Happy to hear this. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out like this: (Visual Studio/Xamarin-iOS/C#)

```
public override void PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
        {
            base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);

            if (segue.Identifier.Equals("my Segue ID"))
            {
                var viewController = (MyDestinationViewController)segue.DestinationViewController;
                viewController.selectedItemInDestinationController = selectedControlStringFromViewController;
            }
        }
```

Perform Segue:

```
this.PerformSegue("my segue ID", this);
```

On Destination ViewController, add:

```
public string selectedControlName;

protected ControlShowController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
{

}
```